# Handling user currency input

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently looking for an elegant solution to achieve currency input by users.
Goal is that the input feels natural, i.e: If you for example type in '1' the cash value shall be: '0.01 $'. If you type another '1' the value shall be: '0.11 $' and so on.

On my specific solution the input is handled by custom input buttons like the one on the windows calculator.

Currently i have handled it like this (The solution is waaaay to complicated but i'm just not finding a simple one)

**Component State:**

```
this.state = {
 cash: 0.00,
};
this.cashInt = 0; //represents the value before the decimal point
this.cashFloat1 = 0; //represenst the first decimal place
this.cashFloat2 = 0; //represents the second decimal place
```

**Custom input button:**

```
<Button
  title={'1'}
  onPress={() => { this.addNumber(1); }}
/>
```

**addNumber function:**

```
addNumber = (number) => {
 if (this.cashInt === 0 && this.cashFloat1 === 0 && this.cashFloat2 === 0) {
   this.cashFloat2 = number;
   this.newCash = 
   parseFloat(`${this.cashInt}.${this.cashFloat1}${this.cashFloat2}`);
   this.setState({ cash: this.newCash }); 
} else if (this.cashInt === 0 && this.cashFloat1 === 0 && this.cashFloat2 !== 0) {
   this.cashFloat1 = this.cashFloat2;
   this.cashFloat2 = number;
   this.newCash = parseFloat(`${this.cashInt}.${this.cashFloat1}${this.cashFloat2}`);
   this.setState({ cash: this.newCash });
} else if (this.cashInt === 0 && this.cashFloat1 !== 0 && this.cashFloat2 !== 0) {
   this.cashInt = this.cashFloat1;
   this.cashFloat1 = this.cashFloat2;
   this.cashFloat2 = number;
   this.newCash = parseFloat(`${this.cashInt}.${this.cashFloat1}${this.cashFloat2}`);
   this.setState({ cash: this.newCash });
} else if (this.cashInt !== 0 && this.cashFloat1 !== 0 && this.cashFloat2 !== 0) {
   this.cashInt = +(this.cashInt.toString() + this.cashFloat1.toString());
   this.cashFloat1 = this.cashFloat2;
   this.cashFloat2 = number;
   this.newCash = parseFloat(`${this.cashInt}.${this.cashFloat1}${this.cashFloat2}`);
   this.setState({ cash: this.newCash });
  }
};
```

So basically what i was doing (because i couldn't find any other way to make it work) is that everytime a new number is being entered the number will get in place of the second decimal place, while the previous values will get offset to the left of the float.

A special case that is not yet handled but should be handled in the solution is the value '00', two zeros after another in order to allow the user to faster input hundreds.

Is there any other way to achieve this? An answer would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLocaleString()` allows you to convert a number to the currency format you wanted.
My understanding is that you don't want user type **dot**, then you could simply divide the number by 100.
Does this match your expectation?

```js
function currency(numStr) {
  let num = parseInt(numStr.replace(/[$,.]/g, ''));
  if (isNaN(num)) { num = 0; }
  else { num = num / 100; }
  return num.toLocaleString('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
}

console.log(currency("a"));
console.log(currency("1"));
console.log(currency("10"));
console.log(currency("123456"));
console.log(currency("$1.00"));
console.log(currency("$10.00"));
console.log(currency("$1,234.56"));
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your input FisNan,
this would work assuming i knew the full numStr. But the user is providing the numbers one by one. So i need a way to handle single number inputs as described above.
Thanks alot again tho!

Comment: @RNative I see. The solution is to use different variables between display value and saved value (eg: rawNum, formatedNum), and uses `onfocus` and `onblur` to switch between 2 variables

Comment: @RNative I added a regular expression to filter out  `$|,|.`.